# Groovy Script in SOAP UI: What is the scope of groovy script in Testing and beneficial for Future growth?

Tags: automated-testing, soapui, groovy

I am working as Manual Tester with 5+ years of experience. I have good experience about SOAPUI. Performed Functional Testing using SOAP.

However the automation can be done using Groovy Script. So, I thought to study groovy script and want to implement in the project for learning purpose.I do not have any experience of Selenium or performance. I thought a way to enter Automation is by learning Groovy as it will take less no of days as compared with Selenium or QTP. I am very much apprehensive that within 15 or 20 days groovy script could be learned and implemented in SOAPUI.

Please let me know whether groovy script has a very limited role in Testing. Whether learning Groovy Script is beneficial or not? Let me know the demand of groovy script.

Answer (score 2):

I started learning automation down the exact same route.

My suggestion is to download a Java IDE and work with Groovy and Java together. Remember Java will, for the most part, work as groovy. So learning Java will help you with Groovy (And slightly vise versa).

Will this lead to a career in automation? Probably not, but it's a good grasping point. Learn the basics with Groovy and SoapUI but keep your eye on Java and Selenium as those a far better on your resume.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your valuable response. According to you I should start with java and groovy and wrap it up in few days and then move over java + selenium. I am studying Java from Head first and understanding the basics of java i.e class,objects, if-else,for loop and then moving ahead with integration of selenium with it.

Comment: Learning groovy with SoapUI will help with learning Java. Part of the issue with learning SoapUI is the documentation is a bit weak. Using an IDE to learn groovy and Java will help with a transition into Selenium, which is a far more desired skill than SoapUI.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy runs on the standard Java runtime.  What this means is that you can use groovy as a stepping stone into java and selenium webdriver.

If I were you I would use Groovy Scripts to extend your SoapUI suites as a starting point.

I found this [walkthrough](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820414/Automating-SoapUI-using-Groovy-A-Walk-Through) really useful when I was starting out
And because loops have some quirks in SoapUI I'd suggest you read [this](https://groovyinsoapui.wordpress.com/) also

Comment: Thanks Ciurleo for your valuable response. I am studying Java from Head first and understanding the basics of java i.e class,objects, if-else,for loop. Along with i am starting learning groovy script from you tube and will try automation in SOAP UI using groovy and java